# Do functions given to the escaping closures create strong reference to the functions owner instance

Tags: swift, closures

I have massive memory leaks in the project I am currently working on. The VC's never disappear from the memory and unfortunately that causes many, many problems right now. The only culprit that I can think of is the way I use closures in the name of readability and simplicity since none of those closures captures self strongly inside. The way I use is as following:

`functionWithEscapingClosure(closure: functionGivenToTheClosure(_:))`

If this creates a strong reference I have soo many refactoring to do, if not I will look elsewhere. Thanks in advance!

I have looked for an explanation to the subject online, searched through the Swift documentation but couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet there is essentially equivalent to:

```swift
functionWithEscapingClosure(closure: { parameter in
    self.functionGivenToTheClosure(parameter)
})
```

So yes, it would implicitly capture a strong reference to the instance that owns the function passed in.

You would need to explicitly do the weak capture to break the cycle:

```swift
functionWithEscapingClosure(closure: { [weak self] parameter in
    self?.functionGivenToTheClosure(parameter)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was what I was afraid of. Do you also know about inner functions which use `self` in there somewhere? Meaning a function inside a function being called in an escaping closure down below? The closure doesn't capture the inner function weakly but the inner function will call `self` in it.

Example:

` func someFunc() {  func innerFunc() {  // self.property used here  } someFuncWithEscapingClosure { innerFunc() } } `